# Select distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very huge database table with above 500k rows. Table contains postal addressess:

```
USERID, ADDRESS, CITY, COUNTY, ZIP , COUNTRY ....
```

I need to get unique county names of one country from the table so I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `county`
FROM `addressess`
WHERE `country` = 'USA'
AND `county` LIKE '%al%' ESCAPE '!'
```

But it is returning me same county names so I tried next with distanct

```
SELECT DISTINCT `county`
FROM `addressess`
WHERE `country` = 'USA'
AND `county` LIKE '%al%' ESCAPE '!'
GROUP BY `county`
```

still same issue, what am I missing

Comment: MySQL doesn't support 500k columns.  Presumably you mean "rows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query (the escape clause and single quotes are unnecessary):

```
SELECT DISTINCT county
FROM addressess
WHERE country = 'USA' AND county LIKE '%al%';
```

returns the distinct names.  The `GROUP BY` does the same thing.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never needed with `GROUP BY`; in this case, the two together do the same as either individually.

If two names *look* the same, that doesn't mean they *are* the same.  There may be trailing spaces or other hidden characters.  You can add `length(county)` and `char_length(county)` to see if the lengths are the same and if the number of letters you see matches what the functions return.

Without sample data or a SQL Fiddle, it is hard to provide more guidance.

Comment: I gave above a pseudo example, after reading your comment I thought it maybe some space around, so to be sure I tried with this query > UPDATE zips set county = TRIM(county);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.47 sec)
Rows matched: 457040  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0   and performed again my search but same issue

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL is enough to generate the distinct county:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT county
    FROM addressess
    WHERE country = 'USA' AND county LIKE '%al%';
```